# Redundant binding parameters on a PDO Insert process

Tags: php, pdo

*FYI: this file is my very first touch with PDO.*

I have converted a mysqli PHP file info a PDO PHP file, it works fine. File's goal is: if user does not pass any value on keys `($ca_key1 - $ca_key3)` just insert data on DB. If keys are passed and do not exist on DB, insert data on DB. If they do exist, echo an error.

I knew PDO could seem redundant, but in this case where I use same parameters up to 3 times on the same file, I ask: is there any way of binding parameter just one time and use it on the 3 executions? For example, `ca_key1` could be just binded once and used on the 3 executions?

If you find any error/mistake on the file apart from this, I would appreciate if you mention me. I'd like to adapt good habits on PDO from the begining.

```
<?php
    session_start();
    include("../conexionbbdd.php");


if($_SESSION['estado'] == 'activo'){

    if (isset($_POST['ca_name'])&&isset($_POST['ca_content'])&&isset($_POST['ca_img'])&&isset($_POST['ca_key1'])&&isset($_POST['ca_key2'])&&isset($_POST['ca_key3'])){ 

        //CHECK IF USER PASSED VALUES ON KEYS
        $ca_key1=$_POST['ca_key1'];
        $ca_key2=$_POST['ca_key2'];
        $ca_key3=$_POST['ca_key3'];

        //IF PASSED, CHECK IF VALUES EXIST ON DB
        if ($ca_key1!=="" || $ca_key2!=="" || $ca_key3!==""){

            $selectKeys= "SELECT ca_key1,ca_key2,ca_key3 FROM ws_campaigns WHERE ca_fk_us_id = :us_id AND ("
                    . "   (ca_key1!='' AND ca_key1 = :ca_key1) OR (ca_key2!='' AND ca_key2 = :ca_key1) OR (ca_key3!='' AND ca_key3 = :ca_key1) "
                    . "OR (ca_key1!='' AND ca_key1 = :ca_key2) OR (ca_key2!='' AND ca_key2 = :ca_key2) OR (ca_key3!='' AND ca_key3 = :ca_key2)"
                    . "OR (ca_key1!='' AND ca_key1 = :ca_key3) OR (ca_key2!='' AND ca_key2 = :ca_key3) OR (ca_key3!='' AND ca_key3 = :ca_key3))"; 

            $statementKeys = $pdo->prepare($selectKeys);

            $statementKeys->bindParam(':us_id', $_SESSION['id'], PDO::PARAM_INT); 
            $statementKeys->bindParam(':ca_key1', $_POST['ca_key1'], PDO::PARAM_STR); 
            $statementKeys->bindParam(':ca_key2', $_POST['ca_key2'], PDO::PARAM_STR); 
            $statementKeys->bindParam(':ca_key3', $_POST['ca_key3'], PDO::PARAM_STR); 

            $statementKeys->execute();

            $cuenta = $statementKeys->rowCount();

            //IF NOT EXIST, INSERT DATA
            if ($cuenta === 0){
                    $insertCampaign = "INSERT INTO ws_campaigns(ca_id,ca_name, ca_content,ca_fk_us_id,ca_img,ca_prefix,ca_key1,ca_key2,ca_key3
                    )VALUES('',:ca_name,:ca_content,:us_id,:ca_img,'34',:ca_key1,:ca_key2,:ca_key3)";

                    $statementInsertCampaign = $pdo->prepare($insertCampaign);

                    $statementInsertCampaign->bindParam(':us_id', $_SESSION['id'], PDO::PARAM_INT); 
                    $statementInsertCampaign->bindParam(':ca_name', $_POST['ca_name'], PDO::PARAM_STR);       
                    $statementInsertCampaign->bindParam(':ca_content', $_POST['ca_content'], PDO::PARAM_STR);             
                    $statementInsertCampaign->bindParam(':ca_img', $_POST['ca_img'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
                    $statementInsertCampaign->bindParam(':ca_key1', $_POST['ca_key1'], PDO::PARAM_STR); 
                    $statementInsertCampaign->bindParam(':ca_key2', $_POST['ca_key2'], PDO::PARAM_STR); 
                    $statementInsertCampaign->bindParam(':ca_key3', $_POST['ca_key3'], PDO::PARAM_STR); 

                    $statementInsertCampaign->execute(); 
                    $newId = $pdo->lastInsertId();
                    echo $newId;
            }
            else{
                echo "No se ha creado la campaña. <br>Alguna de las palabras clave utilizadas ya están presentes en una campaña anterior.";
            }

        }else{
                    //IF NO VALUES PASSED, INSERT DATA
                    $insertCampaign = "INSERT INTO ws_campaigns(ca_id,ca_name, ca_content,ca_fk_us_id,ca_img,ca_prefix,ca_key1,ca_key2,ca_key3
                    )VALUES('',:ca_name,:ca_content,:us_id,:ca_img,'34',:ca_key1,:ca_key2,:ca_key3)";

                    $statementInsertCampaign = $pdo->prepare($insertCampaign);

                    $statementInsertCampaign->bindParam(':us_id', $_SESSION['id'], PDO::PARAM_INT); 
                    $statementInsertCampaign->bindParam(':ca_name', $_POST['ca_name'], PDO::PARAM_STR);       
                    $statementInsertCampaign->bindParam(':ca_content', $_POST['ca_content'], PDO::PARAM_STR);             
                    $statementInsertCampaign->bindParam(':ca_img', $_POST['ca_img'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
                    $statementInsertCampaign->bindParam(':ca_key1', $_POST['ca_key1'], PDO::PARAM_STR); 
                    $statementInsertCampaign->bindParam(':ca_key2', $_POST['ca_key2'], PDO::PARAM_STR); 
                    $statementInsertCampaign->bindParam(':ca_key3', $_POST['ca_key3'], PDO::PARAM_STR); 

                    $statementInsertCampaign->execute(); 
                    $newId = $pdo->lastInsertId();
                    echo $newId;
        }

    }else{
        header('location:../paneles/campana.php?msg=nodata');
    }

}else{
    header('location:../login.php?msg=nopermission');
}

?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, you don't have to bind [explicitly] at all.

PDO is a great step further compared to mysqli, and this is one of it benefits: you can create an array of variables, and pass them directly into `execute()`, instead of binding them one by one - PDO will bind them internally, using `PDO::PARAM_STR` by default, which is not a problem most of time, save for only one case - LIMIT clause parameres.

It is not only greatly reduces amount of code, but also let you to reuse the same set of variables with different queries.

```
$data = array(
    'us_id'   => $_SESSION['id'],
    'ca_name' => $_POST['ca_name'],
    // and so on
);
$stmt->execute($data);
```

Of course, array keys have to match placeholders in the query. If your queries have different sets of placeholders, you will need different arrays as well.

Comment: All clear. Working great with matching placeholders :)